# Working with hook_node_access_grants

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I am currently working with Permission by Term to set simple access control on two node types with terms.

[As noted here](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term/issues/3017347), I believe I found a bug where the access record isn't written the first time the node is saved. That modules internal queries don't return any term ids for this new node, because the data doesn't appear to be committed to the database yet.

This causes a new node to:

1. Show up in a View for a user who does not have access
2. Show up in a Menu for a user who does not have access (menu link)
3. Show up in a search, I assume (I don't have any search of these node types though, so)

You couldn't access the node itself (node/{id}) as a role without access, but the logic that checks that is different...

The second save (and any after) seem to create the right access record in the database. I see it flip from "all" to "permissions_by_term".

So, I resorted to patching in my own functionality to fix what isn't working for me:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access_records_alter().
 *
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term/issues/3017347
 */
function mymodule_node_access_records_alter(&$grants, NodeInterface $node) {
  $grant_to = ['protected_file', 'protected_page'];

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\permissions_by_term\Service\NodeAccess $nodeAccess
   */
  $nodeAccess = \Drupal::service('permissions_by_term.node_access');

  if (
    in_array($node->getType(), $grant_to) &&
    !$nodeAccess->isAccessRecordExisting($node->id()) &&
    !_mymodule_grant_exists($grants, $node)
  ) {
    $grantObject = $nodeAccess->createGrant($node->id(), $node->id());

    $grants[] = [
      'realm'        => $grantObject->realm,
      'gid'          => $grantObject->gid,
      'grant_view'   => $grantObject->grant_view,
      'grant_update' => $grantObject->grant_update,
      'grant_delete' => $grantObject->grant_delete,
      'nid'          => $node->id(),
    ];
  }
}

/**
 * Check the grant array for any duplicate. 
 * A duplicate may occur when permissions are rebuilt.
 *
 * @param array $grants
 * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node
 * @return bool
 */
function _mymodule_grant_exists(array $grants, NodeInterface $node) : bool {
  foreach ($grants as $grant) {
    if ($grant['realm'] === 'permissions_by_term' && $grant['gid'] === $node->id()) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

I ran into a duplicate key error when rebuilding permissions, which is what the second function is for. The `isAccessRecordExisting` method checks the database, and when they're rebuilt the record won't exist.

Admittedly, despite all the time in Drupal, I don't know a whole lot about the access and grant system. The entity type containing a term reference field flagged with Permissions by Term options should get a record inserted with it under its control, but thats not what I am seeing happen.

After I added the code above, all the problems seemed to vanish. Links didn't appear in menus for certain roles, or in Views, saving nodes updated View displays and access appropriately. I could not get it to show me something I should not see.

Is this an adequate fix for what I perceive to be not working, or at least, not working for me? Is there a better way to set a record when the node is created?